# How to adjust the margin and TOF spacing

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, page-numbering, tocloft

I am using a custom document class for writing my dissertation.
You can download the latex file from this link
[click here](https://github.com/soooleh/dissertationLaTeX)

I just want to make sure that I am using the right margin which is 1 inch

```
\pdfpageheight 11in
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\voffset 0pt
\topmargin 0pt
\headheight 0pt
\headsep 0pt
\textheight 9.0in

\oddsidemargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in
\marginparwidth 0.0in
\textwidth 6.5in
```

1. How can I adjust the page number to be 0.75 inches from the bottom?

Regarding the TOC

[image]

2. For long titles, the line must break .5" from the number and the second line must be indented by 0.25". So how can I do that?

Regarding the LOF
[image]

3. They go too close to the number column. How to keep entries at least 1/2'' away from the page number column?

Comment: What have you tried? The `tocloft` package can help with the layout of the ToC etc. and the `geometry` package for the page layout.

Comment: @PeterWilson I tried \def\@pnumwidth{0.5in} and it worked for the sections but not the subsections in the TOC! but how can I adjust the spacing for LOF and LOT?